# Will Auto update in Google Play down grade packages?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

What happens to auto-update in Google Play if an old APK version is made active?

Scenario:
My current (and published) version is 5.11
The previous version is 5.10

If I deactivate 5.11 and activate the older 5.10 version, what will happen to users that have auto update activated and currently have 5.11? Will they auto downgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they will keep their current version. The only way for them to get 5.10 is to uninstall and then re-install from the store. If you released a bad update, you can re-compile and re-release the old version with a higher version number (5.12).

Comment: Higher version code (`versionCode`) is the important part. The version number (`versionName`) can be anything(higher, lower, same, newton's first law of motion etc)

Comment: Actually, the portal does not allow downgrading at all. Despite not changing manifest, I get this when deactivating 511 and activating 510: This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 511 to version 510, which would occur when 
API levels in range 10+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Native platforms containing any of [armeabi-v7a] and 
OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.screen.PORTR